# width and height are wrong in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I code a `SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity`,in `onCreate()` change the orientation to `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`.

It make the screen size is converse.  Follow is my `AndroidManifext.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=". SampleActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/DefaultActivityTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

my SampleActivity.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by wrong and converse? what is the result you get? and show your `onCreate()` code from the `Activity`.

Comment: @th3pat3l the width is the width in portrait, the height is the height in portrait.but i change to landscape.

Comment: Please show your code for the Activity. If you are storing the width and height before the screen is rotated, then, yes, those values are switched

Comment: @cricket_007 i do nothing, you can see my new code

Comment: Then how are you checking the values are reversed?

Comment: Have you tried removing `android:screenOrientation` in the manifest?

Comment: @cricket_007 it doesn't work,i have ever try. and getRequestedOrientation() return landscape

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the height and width you are getting has nothing to do with portrait or landscape. thats just what the phone understands. If you want to know which it is right now, here's what you can do:

```
public boolean isLandscape() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    boolean isLandscape = false;
    Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    d.getSize(size);

    if(size.x > size.y) {
        isLandscape = true;
    }

    return isLandscape;
}
```

This method will return `true` if screen is landscape, if not `false`.

Comment: but i want know why extends AppCompatActivity is wrong but extends FragmentActivity is ok.

Comment: Then you have to post the code on how you are getting width and height values. We can't see how u r getting the wrong values

Comment: @EgosZhang `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, plus you are more than welcome to search through the Android source code